# HighStock chart show data from "Left to Right" not from "Right to Left" on range selector click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a HighStock chart and everything is fine but I have to do something with the range selectors buttons that I have not been able to achieve. What I want is when someone clicks a range selector button (like 1y, 3y, 7y, 10y), the data needs to be shown from the "FromDate" rather than from "ToDate". Let's say I have data from 1995 to 2017 and a user clicks "7y" button, the data in the chart should be from 1995 to 2002, not from 2010 to 2017. Saying the navigator needs to start from the first point only.

In below example, if we click "5y" we want to show data from "2010-09-13 to 2015-09-13" not from "2012-09-13 to 2017-09-13". Can this be achieved? I have not seen this in practice anywhere else using a HighStock chart. It would be helpful if you guys have some thought in this.

Thanks for your time.

Here is the fiddle link which is from the HighStock demo. 
[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/bu5osra3/1/).

```
var seriesOptions = [],
    seriesCounter = 0,
    names = ['MSFT', 'AAPL'];

/**
    * Create the chart when all data is loaded
    * @returns {undefined}
*/
function createChart() {

    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

        rangeSelector: {
            selected:4,
            buttons: [{
                type: "year",
                count: 1,
                text: "1y"
            }, {
                type: "year",
                count: 3,
                text: "3y"
            }, {
                type: "year",
                count: 5,
                text: "5y"
            }, {
                type: "year",
                count: 7,
                text: "7y"
            }, {
                type: "all",
                text: "All"
            }]
        },

        yAxis: {
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return (this.value > 0 ? ' + ' : '') + this.value + '%';
                }
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 2,
                color: 'silver'
            }]
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                compare: 'percent',
                showInNavigator: true
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
            valueDecimals: 2,
            split: true
        },

        series: seriesOptions
    });
}

$.each(names, function (i, name) {

    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=' + name.toLowerCase() + '-c.json&callback=?',    function (data) {

        seriesOptions[i] = {
            name: name,
            data: data
        };

        seriesCounter += 1;

        if (seriesCounter === names.length) {
            createChart();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: This forum topic should be helpful: https://forum.highcharts.com/highstock-usage/anchor-range-selector-to-left-snap-navigation-to-months-t37850/.

Comment: Thanks, @d_paul, this is exactly what I wanted. Cheers :)